# SharePoint 2010 approval workflow assigned to group

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow, approval

We have a list where there is a single approver, but that approver can change at any time. Can the approval workflow have the task participant assigned to a group where only one member of that group is necessary for the item to be approved?

For example, there are four people in the approval group. When one user approves the item, then the other users in the group no longer need to approve it.

Comment: If you set the approval to run in parallel with the assignment being a group, then upon the first rejection or approval, the remaining tasks should get cancelled for the remaining users.

Comment: Who gets the first assignment if it set to serial as a group?

Comment: It is either alphabetical or based on the user's ID as stored in the user information list, I don't recall offhand.

Comment: Can this be mixed? For example with two groups, group1 can be approved by any one person, and group2 can be any one person, but the task is assigned sequentially to group1 then group2?

Comment: Meant to add with assignment stages from comment above.